# How to undo/redo the splitting/union of a feature

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, graphics, undo-redo

I have looked everywhere for examples on this however all I can find are the normal operations, add delete edit and move. Since split and rotate involve creating two features instead of one or combining two features into one, I am not sure how the process would work out.

For example the process for moving a vertex would be as follows:

```
//evt1 = dojo.connect(dojoEditToolbar, 'onVertexFirstMove', function (evt) {
                    //    oldGraphic = evt;
                    //});

                    //evt2 = dojo.connect(dojoEditToolbar, 'onVertexMoveStop', function (evt) {
                    //    if (oldGraphic != null && oldGraphic != undefined) {
                    //        var operation = new esri.dijit.editing.Update({
                    //            featureLayer: evt._graphicsLayer,
                    //            preUpdatedGraphics: [oldGraphic],
                    //            postUpdatedGraphics: [evt]
                    //        });

                    //        myUndoManager.add(operation);
                    //    }
                    //});
```

Comment: The "Editor" widget has this undo/redo functionality built in. Is there specific reasons you don't want to use that? 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/editor-amd.html

Comment: For some reason the widget doesn't seem to be handling the undo/redo functionality of split/union as well as a number of other functionalities.